# What are the default linting analysis options for "flutter analyze"

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using the latest Flutter SDK (2.0.7) in an IDE that uses `flutter analyze` to perform linting. It's clear that `flutter analyze` itself [relies on `dart analyze`](https://flutter.dev/docs/testing/debugging#the-dart-analyzer).  It's also clear that there's some default set of rules used unless you specify otherwise using an [analysis_options.yaml](https://pub.dev/packages/analyzer#configuring-the-analyzer). But I can't figure out what rules they are.  The [docs say](https://dart.dev/guides/language/analysis-options):

> If the analyzer can’t find an analysis options file at the package
> root, it walks up the directory tree, looking for one. If no file is
> available, the analyzer defaults to standard checks.

I'd like to know what these "standard checks" are so that I can start with them as a base and add more.  Ideally, I'd like to start my own `analysis_options.yaml` where the first step is to `include:` the defaults, but I can't figure out how to do this.

There is an [analysis_options.yaml](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/analysis_options.yaml) in the Flutter SDK source tree that says:

> This file contains the analysis options used by Flutter tools, such as
> IntelliJ, Android Studio, and the `flutter analyze` command.

But if I add that to my project root, the results are completely different than the default, i.e. what my IDE shows or if I run the `flutter analyze` command.

Comment: any news on this?